# Limiting a number of connections in C socket programming

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I have the code that allows a user to check/increment/decrement the number in txt file and I need to modify it so only 1 connection would be allowed, but I can't think of any solutions for this.
At first, I though that it would be enough to set the listen second argument to 1, but then I figured out that it's a backlog only and won't affect the amount of available connections.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define SERVER_PORT 1111
FILE *data;

void sndchk(int rc, int listen_sd, int accept_sd);
int readfile();
void writefile(int prekes);

int main(void) {
    int listen_sd, accept_sd, rc, on = 1, d, temp, prekes, recmsg;
    char buffer[80], info[80];
    char msg[80] = "\r\n0-patikrinti prekiu kieki, 1-prideti, 2-atimti, 3-baigti \r\n";
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    pid_t cpid;


    /* Sukuriama programinė jungtis */
    listen_sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    /* Jungties aprašas nustatomas daugkartiniam naudojimui */
    setsockopt(listen_sd,
            SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
            (char *) &on, sizeof (on));

    /* Nustatomi saitai su jungtimi */
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof (addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    rc = bind(listen_sd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof (addr));
    if (rc < 0) {
        perror("bind() failed");
        close(listen_sd);
        exit(-1);
    }

    /* Pradedamas jungties stebėjimas */
    listen(listen_sd, 1);

    while (1) {
        printf("Serveris laukia kliento prisijungimo \r\n");

        /* Užmezgamas ryšys tarp serverio ir kliento */
        accept_sd = accept(listen_sd, NULL, NULL);
        printf("Klientas prisijunge\r\n");

        cpid = fork();
        if (cpid == 0)
            /* Dukterinis procesas */ {
            close(listen_sd);

            rc = send(accept_sd, msg, sizeof (msg), 0);
            sndchk(rc, listen_sd, accept_sd);
            while (1) {
                /* Siunciama informacija */
                /* Is kliento priimama žinutė */
                d = recv(accept_sd, buffer, sizeof (buffer), 0);
                recmsg = atoi(buffer);

                if (recmsg == 0) {
                    prekes = readfile();
                    sprintf(info, "Dabar yra prekiu: %i \r\n", prekes);

                    rc = send(accept_sd, info, 23, 0);
                    sndchk(rc, listen_sd, accept_sd);

                } else if (recmsg == 1) {
                    prekes = readfile();
                    prekes++;
                    sprintf(info, "Dabar yra prekiu: %i \r\n", prekes);

                    rc = send(accept_sd, info, 23, 0);
                    sndchk(rc, listen_sd, accept_sd);

                    writefile(prekes);
                } else if (recmsg == 2) {
                    prekes = readfile();
                    prekes--;
                    sprintf(info, "Dabar yra prekiu: %i \r\n", prekes);

                    rc = send(accept_sd, info, 23, 0);
                    sndchk(rc, listen_sd, accept_sd);

                    writefile(prekes);
                } else if (recmsg == 3) {
                    printf("Baigiamas rysys su klientu!\r\n");
                    close(accept_sd);
                    close(listen_sd);
                    exit(-1);
                }
            }
            printf("Baigiamas rysys su klientu!\r\n");
            close(accept_sd);
            close(listen_sd);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}

int readfile() {
    int value;
    data = fopen("./file.txt", "r");
    fscanf(data, "%d\r\n", &value);
    fclose(data);
    return value;
}

void writefile(int prekes) {
    data = fopen("./file.txt", "w");
    fprintf(data, "%d\r\n", prekes);
    fclose(data);
}

void sndchk(int rc, int listen_sd, int accept_sd) {
    if (rc <= 0) {
        perror("send() failed");
        close(listen_sd);
        close(accept_sd);
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't reap your children. And there's no point to your forking. So first of all, stop forking and handle the request in the parent. If you're actually asking how to limit the number of requests being handled concurrently, that's all you need to do. If you really do want to limit the number of connections as you asked, simply remove `while (1)` as well.

Comment: You can either not accept (i.e. don't run it in a loop), or accept and close the connections you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

I take you to mean that you want only one connection *at a time*.  In that case, the solution couldn't be easier: **don't `fork()`**.  After accepting a connection, do the needed work in the single thread of the single server process, until that work is complete. Then close the client connection and loop back to accept another.

Or if you meant that you want the process to accept only one connection *ever*, then skip the looping back part and just terminate instead.

Comment: The first option - I want to have only one active connection at a time. Will try to follow your advice, thanks :)